# Setter for Realm object not invoked

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm attempting to use setters to remove the need for calling code to have to use Realm transactions whenever properties of a Realm object are being updated, but without success.

For example suppose I have got the following Realm class:

```
@interface Caller : RLMObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  * _Nullable name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  * _Nullable number;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int someInt;
@end
```

With a setter for someInt as below:

```
@implementation Caller
- (instancetype) init
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (void)setSomeInt: (int) newValue
{
    RLMRealm *realm = [self realm];
    if (realm)
    {
        [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    }
    _someInt = newValue;
    if (realm)
    {
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];
    }
}
```

Now if I create a new object and set someInt then setSomeInt gets called:

```
Caller* caller = [[Caller alloc] init];
caller.someInt = 8;
```

Fine, but if the caller object is then saved saved to Realm and then `someInt` is changed again, then the following error occurs:

> 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a
>   write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance
>   first.'

But this is exactly what the point of setter is trying to prevent -  to create a transaction if necessary, but the Realm error is "occurring before" `setSomeInt` is getting called in this case. Why is the setter not being called when the object has been stored to Realm, but it is called prior to that, and is there a solution without having to set the property explicitly via a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that [Realm does not support overriding getters and setters for persisted properties](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#realm-object-setters--getters-cannot-be-overriden).

The reason you observe the behavior that you do is because Realm inserts custom getters / setters for instances of your class that are managed by Realm. These getters / setters are responsible for reading / writing data from the underlying Realm file. The workaround mentioned in the link above (use separate properties that are ignored by Realm for the custom get / set behavior, storing through to a non-ignored property) may work for your purposes.